# PHP mysql_num_rows die error

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create one page, where users add their informations..
I allready have that page created, but my real problem its down code..

I have some kind of problem, with that part of code:

```
<?php
//Connect to DB
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","USER","PASS") or die("Database Error");
mysql_select_db("DB",$db);

//Get ID from request
$idstire = isset($_GET['idstire']) ? (int)$_GET['idstire'] : 0;

//Check id is valid
if($idstire > 0)
{
//Query the DB
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stiri2 WHERE idstire = " . $idstire);
if($resource === false)
{
    die("Eroare la conectarea cu baza de date");
}

if(mysql_num_rows($resource) == 0)
{
    die("Se pare ca stirea nu mai exista, sau a fost stearsa. <a     href='http://www.wanted-web.ro'>ACASA</a>");
}

$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);

echo "
<div class='main-article-content'>
<h2 class='article-title'>asd</h2>

<div class='article-photo'>
<img src='" . $user['poza'] . "' class='setborder' alt='' />
</div>

<div class='article-controls'>

<div class='date'>
<div class='calendar-date'>" . $user['data'] . "</div>

                            </div>

<div class='right-side'>
<div class='colored'>
<a href='' class='icon-link'><span class='icon-text'></span>Printeaza articol</a>
<a href='#' class='icon-link'><span class='icon-text'></span>Trimite prietenilor</a>
                                </div>

                                <div>
<a href='#' class='icon-link'><span class='icon-text'></span>de Cristian Cosmin D.</a>
<a href='#' class='icon-link'><span class='icon-text'></span>39 comentarii</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

<div class='clear-float'></div>


                        </div>


<div class='shortcode-content'>
<p>" . $user['nume'] . " , " . $user['prenume'] . " , " . $user['varsta'] . " , " . $user['localitatea'] . "</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>


";
}

$query = "UPDATE stiri2 SET accesari = accesari + 1 WHERE idstire=\"" . $idstire . "\"";
$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
?>
```

It's show me error from here:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($resource) == 0)
{
    die("Se pare ca stirea nu mai exista, sau a fost stearsa. <a     href='http://www.wanted-web.ro'>ACASA</a>");
}
```

I really dont understand why!?

Can someone explain me?
Thank you!

Comment: Is this new code? If it is you might want to consider not using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Consider [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: Perhaps you should consider telling us what error you get.

Comment: Is there any record in `stiri2` table maybe?

Comment: That error:  **bold**Se pare ca stirea nu mai exista, sau a fost stearsa. <a     href='http://www.wanted-web.ro'>ACASA</a>**bold**

Comment: table records are "id , nume , prenume , varsta , localitatea, numep, poza, data, accesari" . when i write details on form,they are added in database.. but in that page show me that error

Comment: have you tried echo `$idstire` ? and see if there is values !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_query should have the second parameter as the connection which is in your case $db

```
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stiri2 WHERE idstire = " . $idstire,$db);
```

if this also not works then use mysql_error to know the exact error

```
$row=mysql_num_rows($resource);
if($row)
{

}
else
{
    mysql_error();
}
```

this will show you if there is problwm in mysql_num_rows

Comment: i changed with your code, but now not show me informations from database.. Not show any error, but not show informations added.. I hope to understand what i say

Comment: @MuzicaVeche: You **do** understand that there **is no** information to show, right?

Comment: now i see the error.. i try to resolve that.. ty a lot brothers for help me.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is, that your SQL Statement does not have any results.

Please check if your database contains some rows for this *idstire*.

Comment: idstire row exist , and informations are added succesfully .. but still show me the error on page

Comment: Try to execute the SQL Statement directly in PHPMyAdmin to test it.

Comment: its show me that:   `ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 3
STR: //
SQL: 

//Get ID from request
$idstire = isset($_GET['idstire']) ? (int)$_GET['idstire'] : 0; `

Comment: Paste this "SELECT * FROM stiri2 WHERE idstire = X" in to PMA and replace X with the idstire you normally use for test purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If $_GET['idstire'] is not set, you are setting $idstire to 0. Is there any entry in the table for idstire=0?

You can print your php query with $idstire replaced with its value. Take that query and execute in phpmyadmin to see the error. Also verify that row exists for the value of $idstire being used in the query.

Comment: i see my error was in form page.. i resolved that.. ty a lot brothers for opening my eyes !